# Ошибка при установке готового пакета PyAudio

Tags: pyaudio

я новичок в программировании, поэтому не понимаю почему вылезает эта ошибка, хотя готовый пакет для моей версии питона находится на компьютере, заранее спасибо.

[image]

Comment: Нужно не «на компьютере», а в той папке, откуда запускается команда. Текст ошибки-то читай целиком.

Comment: то есть нужно закинуть файл в C:\Windows\System32?

Comment: Ээ, ну можно и так, конечно, но обычно или запускают pip из нужной папки, или пишут полный путь к файлу.